# How to drop voltage drop from 61V to 50V at 1.85A?

Tags: voltage, dc

Trying to add my analysis to all the comments suggests that I am taking a wholly wrong route and trying to add a regulator between the output of the PSU and before the input of the POE is not intelligent.  If the assumption that the POE board is designed for 48 VDC is right ( the manufacturer/supplier either does not know or avoids the question ) then the solution is simple. Ditch the present PSU and provide a quality 48 VDC version.  I have now discovered, from the p.c.b. who made the PSU in China, and have obtained a price from them of $6.72 and a rating of 52VDC + - 5%.  But when I tested I found 64VDC.  So I conclude that the POE supplier bought-in the PSU because it was cheap without checking if it was any use or not, or even right for the application. So I have been barking up the wrong tree but thanks to all those who responded: your answers did clear my mind. A message for Olin:  Google blocked your website on the grounds that it was a spreader of walware.

What is the most simple and best way to reduce a 1.85amp 61VDC supply to a 1.85amp 50VDC supply?

---

The reason is a sad story.  A friend of mine has imported over 400 8 port POE units, to power eight IP cameras over the same cable as the video returns.  With the POE units came stand-alone PSU's rated at 110/240 AC input and 52VDC output at 1.85 amps.  The POE units delivered to customers some caught fire. I tested the PSU's and some delivered 61VDC and some others as high as 64VDC.  If the rating of 52VDC marked on the case of the PSU is correct for  the required voltage of the POE ( I would have expected 48 ) then perhaps the safe voltage is 52, and perhaps the POE components are surviving at 61, but perhaps 64 is just that bit too much and a diode is getting hot enough to start a fire.

My opinion is that there is nothing wrong with the POE board if it is given the right voltage, so it 'aint broke so don't fix it.  The problem is the power supply marked as 52 plus 5%, and to me that suggests a nominal safe voltage of 55 ( but I do not know).  So what is the solution?

My solution, knowing the Chinese mindset, is try to add a small module between the PSU and the POE that pulls the input voltage down by about 10 volts.  This module, by my calculations will have to handle a maximum of 64VDC at its input and be able to deliver ( a regulated? ) 55VDC with a dissipation of about 40 watts.  Because there is so much not known a variable control over the output would be an advantage.

To scrap all the PSU's and buy new PSU's would be a heavy cost, so, in my opinion, a small interface module based perhaps on a $1.33 P Channel MOSFET would only need a suitable Zener, the pot and a few C's and R's, and a mighty heatsink.  The nearest Zener I could find is the TL431a but that is rated at only 36VDC so some trickery is needed round it. The cheap MOSFET I found is the Si7113DN but I have failed to find it in a TO220 package.  I also found the NTE66 which is 220 and can then be heat sinked but the cost was £8.00 each.

So overall I do not really know what I am doing and need help.

Comment: Is the load going to draw a constant 1.85 amps, or will the draw vary under different conditions?  Is the load a type which requires a constant-current power supply to limit its current?   Or is it a normal "I want 50 volts" type constant-voltage device, and it happens to draw 1.85 amps?

Comment: What needs 50V?  Most devices can tolerate a significant range of voltages.  What is the source?  Why is it 61v? Is it adjustable in any way?  It also will not be precisely 61v, it will have range.

Comment: Given the voltage drop and current, the power dissipation in a linear regulator would be high enough that a switching regulator would really make sense.  But the question seems a bit suspicious - while legitimate needs for this kind of thing exist, "going about things in the wrong way" is the most usual way to arrive at such a perceived need, so people want to know what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: A 5.95 ohm resistor?

Comment: Explain : WHY? / Application, Is therea constant load? One or many?

Comment: Now you know why someone dumped 400 cheap POE switches.  Your "friend" did something stupid and got caught.  There is no good way out of this.  Trying to kludge this and build 400 voltage dropper units will cost more than just getting a bunch of proper 48 V power supplies.  Again, this is a great example of how stupidity costs money.

Comment: POE has handshaking signals to decide how much power to deliver. If things are starting on fire, then the design is out of the POE spec or its a bad design. The normal procedure for fixing this problem is to make the company fix it or get your money back. If you can't trust the company then don't buy.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to approach this, but there is no simple *and* best. They include (in no particular rating order)

a) determining whether your appliance will in fact tolerate 61v
b) buying a 50v power supply
c) buying a 61v appliance
d) using a series linear regulator that dissipates over 20 watts
e) using a switch mode power supply that may do it with a loss of a few watts
f) using a dropper zener, if the voltages are exact, with >20W loss
g) using a dropper resistor, if the voltages and currents are exact and unchanging, with >20W loss
h) using a shunt linear regulator, with >>20W loss

Obviously each option has different cost, power, simplicity tradeoffs. You will get better advice if you reveal more about your situation and your constraints. It's unlikely that each of the voltages you quote has a +/-0  tolerance. As the voltage range is an important part of the problem, include that in your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing here is that UNITS INSTALLED IN BUILDINGS CAUGHT FIRE, the power supplies are clearly crap, but the POE distribution units (which are the bit that caught fire) are also clearly unfit for purpose (There is no way 60 odd volts up a bit of telecoms kit designed for 48V should cause a fire)...

I might allow an overvoltage to cause a functional failure (But 61V on a 48V product would rate as pretty piss poor quality of implementation), but you are supposed to design things so that fire is unlikely whatever happens.

Cheaper to replace the lot with decent kit then it is to have a fire cause serious damage to a building, especially a CUSTOMERS building (You could be looking at $MILLIONS in liability). Recall the lot, crush them and give the customers proper kit instead (Cisco make nice stuff for this, as do Arista, Juniper, HP).

Sorry, but this is probably not a simple or cheap fix to the hardware you have.